# css: column-count property , IE10 displays not like other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, column-count

Here is a http://jsfiddle.net/nAhPj/ link.
The page looks the same way in Chrome, FF, Safari, but not in IE10.
It should be:

```
1A 2A 3A 4A
1B 2B 3B 4B
1C 2C 3C
1D 2D 3D
```

Why doesn't it look in IE10 the same way as in Chrome, FF, Safari? How to fix the IE10 issue? Is that a bug?

**P.S. Unfortunately, the solution should be to OVERRIDE the css , not to modify html or css.** Otherwise, I would found the solution and won't ask this question.

Here are the images how it looks in Chrome vs IE10:
[image]

Comment: What *does* it look like in IE10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most simple solution to have a cross browser solution (i mean recent browsers) is to use `<li>` as blocks.

Position `display: inline-block` css property on your `<li>`, and then use `float` and `width`  properties to position them as you want. And you can do responsive design with this.

Comment: Thank you! Applying  display: inline-block; and width:200px; to the <li> is the solution.